# ¿Cómo agregar un elemento a un array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, array, object

tengo este ejemplo:

```
var arr = [{'a':12,'b':21},{'a':23,'b':32}];
```

Quisiera agregar un elemento más, me quede algo así:

```
[{
  a:12,
  b:21,
  c:1
},{
 a:23,
 b:32,
 c:2
}]
```

"C" sería mi elemento nuevo, lo hice así:

```
var k=1;
for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++)
{
  arr[i].push({"c":k});
 k++;
}
```

Me marca error pero no sé por qué, ¿me podrían ayudar?

Comment: `arr.push({c:1});`

Comment: ¿Qué error te muestra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te marca error porque estas usando `push` en un objeto y no en un arreglo. Para agregar el key 'c' en tus objetos dentro del arreglo podrias hacer esto:

```
var k=1;
for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++)
{
  arr[i]["c"] = k; // accedes al arreglo y agregas el key 'c' y le asignas el valor de k
 k++;
}
```

tambien podrias hacerlo asi: `arr[i].c = k;` porque c es un nombre valido para un key de un objeto.